# How to code logs / Dealing with NaN's

Tags: java, nan, logarithm, natural-logarithm

I am trying to make a method that finds an approximation of the natural log of a variable using a Taylor Series.

I am aware of the `Math.log(a)` method and do not wish to use it here.

The problem is that for numbers greater than 2 the result returned is `NaN`.
This is only true when outer `for` loop is set to execute a large number of times.
For example `n < 10` gives a result, but not an accurate one.
However, the more the outer `for` loop runs, the more accurate the result will be.

Taylor Series for finding `ln(x)` (essentially what I'm trying to write in java code)
[image: Taylor Series for finding <code>ln(x)</code>]

```
public static double nat_log(double x) {
  double result = 0.0;
  for (int n = 1; n < 10000; n++) {
    double a = x - 1;
    int b = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
      a *= (x - 1);
      b *= -1;
    }
    result += b * a / n;
  }
    return result;
  }
```

My logic is that at some point `a` becomes too large and gets read as a `NaN`, thus throwing the rest of the code off. So I tried a version using a `while` loop and the `Double.isNaN(double)` method to check if `a` ever became `NaN`. The result was an infinite loop.

```
public static double nat_log(double x) {
  double result = 0.0;
  double a = x - 1;
  int count = 1;
  while (Double.isNaN(a) == false) {
     a = x - 1;
     int b = -1;
     for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
       a *= (x - 1);
       b *= -1;
     }
     result += b * (a / count);
     count++;
   }
 }
```

At this point i'm really stuck and not sure exactly where the problem lies, maybe I'm just trying to do something without the proper tools.

Comment: I'm not clear on whether you already knew this or not, but this Taylor series will not converge if x > 2.   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions

Comment: Also, I don't think you're really getting `NaN`.  If you keep multiplying numbers and they get too large, eventually you'll get "infinity", which is different from `NaN`.  That would explain the infinite loop.  You might want to change your second algorithm to check `Double.isInfinite()` to verify this for yourself.

Comment: If you really want an algorithm that works for x > 2, I think your best bet is to divide it by _e_ repeatedly until it becomes < 2, and count the number of times you divide.  If the count is `N`, then add `N` to the result of the Taylor series.

Answer (score -1):

Your while loop becomes an infinate loop when count overflows

Comment: The `while` doesn't look at `count` at all, so this answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ajb yes I know,  but it could make a never an NAN